# Cordova - connecting to a proxy server

Tags: android, ios, cordova, proxy

I have a **cordova** application targeting both iOS and android platforms. Under certain conditions, when the user, who is in a specific group, logs in to the application (using normal his data plan), I want all the HTTP calls to be router through a proxy server which has an authentication based on username and password. I need to know how do I enable the application to connect to a proxy.

thanks

Comment: I am unsure if I understand your question. You would like to change the URL of the requests after the user has logged in depending on some conditions?

Comment: Under certain conditions... you need different URL to connect to a proxy

Comment: I would launch the application, authenticate the user (using login/password) - If the user is authenticated - then I want to route the user to a proxy with username and password - using cordova code and then ensure that any further communication to or from the app is always happening via this proxy.